# How do i find the discount amount based on product that matches shopping cart price rule in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to find the discount amount which match the shopping cart rule based on product. I want to get discount amount that matches my product price rule based on product details(product id, sku). here is the code i am using but its not working.

```
<?php 
$products_id = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getId(), 'id');
$_p = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($products_id);
$price_rules = array();
$rules = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Collection')
                       ->load();
foreach($rules as $rule){
  $rule->afterLoad(); 
}  

$quoteId = $objectManager->getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId(); 
$real_quote = $objectManager->getSingleton('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);                
$product = $objectManager->get('sales/quote_item')->setQuote($real_quote)->setProduct($_p);  
$product->setAllItems(array($_p));                 
$product->getProduct()->setProductId($_p->getEntityId());    
foreach($rules as $rule) 
{  
    if ($rule->getConditions()->validate($product))  
    {            
        echo ':)';
        echo $rule->getData('discount_amount');
    }        
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should init an quote item like this:

```
$real_quote = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();
$item = $objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->setQuote($real_quote)->setProduct($product);
$item->setAllItems(array($product));
$item->getProduct()->setProductId($product->getEntityId());
```